# Is it possible to post to users' feed without posting on their wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I would like my Facebook app to post personalized updates to users on their feeds, without posting on their walls.

Answer (score 4):

Per the facebook documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ the feed **IS** the wall.

> **feed**  The user's wall.

So the answer is "No".

Comment: Wall and feed is different as Juicy's answer explains.

Comment: If that is so, please log a defect against Facebook's documentation at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ so they can fix it.  They currently still show that the "Feed" is "The user's wall".

Answer (score 2):

There is actually no way to post something on a "Wall" but "Feed" in Facebook via API. They are practically the same place.

You can create `post` in `feed` and Facebook will decide if that post will appear in user's wall according to many aspects that wasn't clearly described (and possibly will never be due to Timeline).

There is also a bit old but interesting article [Facebook’s Wall vs. News Feed Explained](http://www.pixelcoaching.com/public/facebooks-wall-vs-news-feed-explained/) by Pixel Coaching that you may want to read.